# Unable to generate mode files in apertium for Eng-fra language pair

Tags: translation, apertium

I am trying to make a standalone language pair using apertium. I compiled the language package for eng-fra.But the mode files are not generated it shows the following error.

> apertium-validate-modes modes.xml modes.xml:6: element mode: validity
>   error : No declaration for attribute gendebug of element mode
>   modes.xml:50: element mode: validity error : No declaration for
>   attribute gendebug of element mode Document modes.xml does not
>   validate against /usr/share/apertium/modes.dtd make: ***
>   [modes/fra-eng.mode] Error 3

please help me to resolve this...Do I have to create the mode files seperately

Answer (score 2):

Already answered at https://sourceforge.net/p/apertium/discussion/481031/thread/56daa7e8/ – but for anyone else stumbling upon this error, the solution is to update apertium, see http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Install_Apertium_core_using_packaging (although the most recent Debian/Ubuntu version will also work in this case).

The `gendebug` attribute was added to modes.xml some years ago. The https://github.com/apertium/apertium-fra-eng/blob/4ecf87a6410a900be87a6d98f80fdd2f93aeb73b/modes.xml validates fine with the current version of apertium.